# Using pan along with swipe is not working in Hammer.JS

Tags: swipe, hammer.js, pan

I have a grid where pan should be used for multiple selection of grid rows.  Swipe should be used from scrolling the rows. When I use both pan and swipe always pan fires not swipe.

I tried `recognizewith`.  It didn't work for my use case.

While swiping, pan should not fire and vice versa. I tried all permutation of velocity and threshold values.

How can I prevent pan and swipe from interfering with each other?

Comment: It's a misunderstanding that "while swiping, pan should not fire and vice versa".  Swipe is only fired at the point the user releases a touch with sufficient velocity; pan is fired continuously as the user drags while touching.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I've found is to use one `Hammer.Manager` for swipe, and another `Hammer.Manager` for pan (I have no idea if this is the proper way to do it, but it's unfortunate that they don't seem to play nicely together in some cases).

You will probably want to create the swipe manager first so that you get `swipe` events before `panend` events.

Example:

```
const hammerSwipe = new Hammer.Manager(
  element,
  {
    recognizers: [
      [Hammer.Swipe, { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL }],
    ],
  }
))
hammerSwipe.on('swipe', this._handleSwipe)

const hammerPan = new Hammer.Manager(
  element,
  {
    recognizers: [[Hammer.Pan]],
  }
))
hammerPan.on('panmove', this._handlePan)
hammerPan.on('panend', this._handlePanEnd)
```